# 403 Forbidden Access on port 443 (SSL)

Tags: linux, apache, http, ssl, https

I am trying to set up SSL on my webpage located in local network. Firstly, I generated a certificate using openssl and modified some .conf files in apache2 directory. Unfortunately, I've got `403 forbidden access error`. It concerns only `443 port (HTTPS)`. `HTTP (80)` works perfectly fine. BTW Encryption works because my browser shows `Your connecton is encrypted...`.

httpd.conf
Only including files below

default-vhost.conf (port 80) - works

```
<VirtualHost 10.83.200.80:80>
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs"

    <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        Options None
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

default-vhost-ssl.conf (443) - does not work

```
#<IfDefine SSL>
#<IfDefine !NOSSL>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    ServerName 10.83.200.80:443
    ServerAlias 10.83.200.80:443
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs"
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/access_log

    <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        Options None
        Order allow,deny

        AllowOverride All

        Require all granted
    </Directory>    

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5   
    #SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
    #SSLHonorCipherOrder on 

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server.crt
    #SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-dsa.crt

    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/server.key
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/server-dsa.key

    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca.crt

    #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/apache2/ssl.crt
    #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

    #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl
    #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

    #SSLVerifyClient require
    #SSLVerifyDepth  10

    #   Access Control:
    #   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
    #   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
    #   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
    #   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
    #   for more details.
    #<Location />
    #SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
    #            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
    #            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
    #           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
    #</Location>

    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "/srv/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_request_log   ssl_combined

    #
    # some Rewrite stuff for sharedssl
    #
    #RewriteEngine on
    ##RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-rewrite-ssl_log"
    ##RewriteLogLevel 3
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^webmail\..* [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^/$ https://sharedssl.example.com/roundcube/ [L,R]
    #RewriteRule ^/$ /roundcube [R]

</VirtualHost>                                  

#</IfDefine>
#</IfDefine>
```

As you can see,  for both files, configrations are almoust the same.

Greetings.

Comment: go through http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/

Comment: Is your apache 2.4 or higher? `Require all granted` is a new thing on that version and could not work on lower versions, and because of the `order` directive on your configuration, it could be returning the `403` error. Try using `Allow from all` instead, just like your `80` port configuration.